# How would I replace a single quote (') with a backslash then single quote (\') using sed?

Tags: sed, terminal

How would I replace a single quote (') with a backslash then single quote (\') using sed?

```
sed s/\'/\\\'/
```

won't work because you never get to write the literal .

```
sed ":a;N;s/\'/\\'/g" <file1 >file2
```

won't work because the backslash will no longer escape the quote, it get's treated like a regex quote.

Comment: Works on Mac OS - your mileage may vary...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just quote the replacement

```
$ echo \' | sed s/\'/"\\\'"/
$ \'
```

e.g

```
$ cat text1
this is a string, it has quotes, that's its quality
$ sed s/\'/"\\\'"/ text1 > text2
$ cat text2
this is a string, it has quotes, that\'s its quality
```

Comment: +1  :)
The inverse of that was exactly what I needed.
```sed s/"\\\'"/\'/g```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
sed -e s/\'/\\\\\'/g input > output
```

To prove that this works:

```
echo "Hello 'World'" | sed -e s/\'/\\\\\'/g
```

The output should be:

```
Hello \'World\'
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:
sed "s,',BBBB',g" file
where B is a back-slash ... that is 4 backslashes ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the -e option.

sed -e s/\'/\\'/g file2

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
<<<"''''" sed 's/'\''/\\&/;s/\('"'"'\)\(..\)$/\\\1\2/;'s/\'\'$/\\\\\'\'/";s/'$/\\\'/"
\'\'\'\'
```

This is showing 4 separate ways in which a single quote can be replaced by a back slash followed by a single quote, using sed.

1. `<<<\' sed 's/'\''/\\&/'`
2. `<<<\' sed 's/\('"'"'\)/\\\1/'`
3. `<<<\' sed  s/\'/\\\\\'/`
4. `<<<\' sed "s/'/\\\'/"`

Putting them altogether to replace four single  quotes the above regexps achieve the desired result.