# With awk, how to match the backslash character when followed by single quote (yes that is two characters)

Tags: design-patterns, awk, sed, replace, match

I've a log file which is periodically generated by an automated process I do not control.  There are many instances in this log file of a backslash character (not as an 'escape') immediately followed by a single quote mark  `\'`.  Thus it is a two character text pattern.

I am looking for awk or sed examples which will match the two character `\'` pattern, and replace it with the single character pattern of a single quote `'`.  In my environment, I'm limited to bash and standard gnu-utils; fancy stuff like python or perl aren't available to the target environment where the solution to this problem will operate.

I've attempted:

`cat F1.log | awk '{gsub(/\\t/,"\t")}1' | awk '{gsub(/\\'/,"\'")}1' > F2.log`

`cat F1.log | awk '{gsub(/\\t/,"\t")}1' | sed 's/$(echo "\134\047")/$(echo \047")/g' > F2.log`

Side note:  The 1st in-line awk has been a long-standing working tool to match/transform the two-character pattern of `\t` instances into the single character `t`.  I simply added a new in-line awk instance of the same command and replaced the `t` with `'`, but the result isn't syntactically correct.

For the 1st, the error is:  `` -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)' ``

For the 2nd, the error is:  `sed: -e expression #1, char 36: Invalid back reference`

Here is an instance from a recent log file with an appropriate data line piped to `od -bc`:

```
0000000 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 147
                                                                      g
0000020 160 147 072 040 153 145 171 142 157 170 040 134 047 057 164 155
          p   g   :       k   e   y   b   o   x       \   '   /   t   m
0000040 160 057 056 147 156 165 160 147 057 160 165 142 162 151 156 147
          p   /   .   g   n   u   p   g   /   p   u   b   r   i   n   g
```

I know I've got something wrong with single/double-quotes and/or paren's.  I have extensively searched both StackOverflow first and then google, without finding any solution.

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you need to remove \ only before `t` and `'` or would result will be ok if all \ would be removed?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your cannot do the same thing with a singlequote, is because your script is written in single quotes:

```
awk '{gsub(/\\'/,"\t")}1'
#   ^         ^         ^
#   |        ???        End of string
#   Start of string
```

You'll need to escape the single quote, by using one of the following patterns:

```
'stringA'"'"'stringB'
'stringA'\''stringB'
```

or you can type the octal code for a single quote in the pattern and replacement:

```
awk '{gsub(/\\\047/,"\047")}1'
```

Gluing it all together and we get:

```
awk '
  {
    gsub(/\\t/,"\t")
    gsub(/\\\047/,"\047")
  }
  1
' F1.log > F2.log
```

Two things to consider:

1. Why are your data "corrupted" in the first place?
2. Should you add support for all the other escape sequences as well?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
gawk -c/mawk/nawk 'gsub(/[\134][\047]/,"\f")+1'
```

> `gawk (any mode other than -c) 'gsub(/[\\][\047]/,"\f")+1'`

Reason being gawk's default regex engine behaves rather differently. i've hashed out a few different variants of how the regex can go wrong :

```
gawk  -e '{ print a="\011left]\134\47right" }'

    left]\'right

--[ CORRECT ]-----------------------------------
sub(/\\\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\[\47]/,"\f", a)
sub(/[\\][\47]/,"\f", a)
sub(/[\\134][\47]/,"\f", a)

    left]
         right

--[ MATCHED WRONG CHAR ]----------------------------
sub(/[\134][\47]/,"\f", a)

    left
        \'right

--[ ERRORED OUT ]—————————————————

sub(/\\\\\134\\47/,"\f", a)
gawk: cmd. line:1: error: Invalid back reference: /\\\\\\\47/
sub(/\\\134\\47/,"\f", a)
gawk: cmd. line:1: error: Invalid back reference: /\\\\\47/
sub(/[\134]\47/,"\f", a)
gawk: cmd. line:1: error: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[\]'/

--[ NOTHING MATCHED ]-----------------------------------

sub(/\\\[\47]/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\\[\47]/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\\\\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\\\134[\47]/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\\\134\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\\\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\\134[\47]/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\\134\\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\\134\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\134[\47]/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\\134\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\134[\47]/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\134\\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\\134\47/,"\f", a)
sub(/\134\47/,"\f", a)
    left]\'right
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a relevant answer here:  [How would I replace a single quote (') with a backslash then single quote (\') using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070812/how-would-i-replace-a-single-quote-with-a-backslash-then-single-quote-u?rq=1)

The inverse of the primary answer did the trick.
`sed s/"\\\'"/\'/g`

Comment: Don;t do that, it's using all the quotes incorrectly and is missing the script delimiter quotes.